# What does a post-industrial world look like if there was no oil or gas, only coal?

Tags: society, technological-development, energy, industrial-age

What might the world look like if easily accessible oil and gas wasn’t available and  coal was the only option?

I’m trying to understand was a post-apocalyptic industrial society might look like (I’m assuming they are starting from scratch. No bootstrapping straight to PV cells). We have already exploited most easy to get to oil and gas so any civilization coming after us will have to rely on coal and wood to power an industrial civilization.

Comment: The word [post-industrial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post-industrial_society) does not mean what you think it means. And anyway, if they have coal they are all set. Coal can be [gasified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gasification) into [syngas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syngas) and can be [liquefied](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coal_liquefaction) into synthetic fuel. For example, liquid fuel produced by the [Fischer-Tropsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer–Tropsch_process) process was used on extensively by  Nazi Germany and South Africa; it is not even overly expensive.

Comment: If you want to avoid photovoltaics, you can still have small wind and waterwheels hydroelectric. For electricity, pumping water, running mills etc.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase the "[steam age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Age_of_Steam)" is a euphemism for an era (specifically, a period of industrialization in parts of Europe between roughly 1770 and 1914) in which the primary fuel was coal, which powered steam boilers, which were used to provide useful energy, before petroleum became available on an economic basis and led to the "diesel era" because it was superior to coal as a fuel in many practical respects.

Until the last few decades, coal fired power plants were the primary source of electricity and aren't that difficult to create as long as you can create or locate magnets. Basically, a coal fired power plant uses steam to spin magnets in an electric coal to generate electricity by induction, which is a very simple process taught in first year college physics. It would take only one person with a surviving college physics textbook to revive this technology. There would also be plenty of magnets that could be scavenged from the ruins of the collapsed society to make new power plants, rather than mined from scratch.

Basically, enhanced by the residual and widely disseminated scientific knowledge you would have in a post-apocalyptic world without direct oil and gas resources, you would end up with something resembling "[steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk)" rather than a "post-industrial" era which is pretty much what the modern U.S. is typical of.

So, assuming battery technology was not recovered as quickly, you'd have steam powered machinery in factory like settings and for example, in trains and other powered machines remote from urban electric grids, and electrical grid powered machines and vehicles (like intercity trolleys and subways) in urban areas.

Of course, as noted by @AlexP in the comments:

> Coal can be gasified into syngas and can be liquefied into synthetic
> fuel. For example, liquid fuel produced by the Fischer-Tropsch process
> was used on extensively by Nazi Germany and South Africa; it is not
> even overly expensive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what would be the size of the post apocalyptic population. If you simply cut the size to a third or a quarter of the current population it would still be so big that there would not be enough coal to cover the energy need. Hydroelectric, biomass, gas from decomposing matter and anything else easily exploitable would still be part of the mix. So you can still imagine a stratified society with people hustling and shoving to get their access to the scarce resources.

You can imagine cities sharply divided in rich and poor areas, in Victorian Britain the prevalent winds used to push the smog to the eastern part of the city and all rich people lived in the western side where air was cleaner.

The oil wars would become like the current war in Ukraine 'coal wars' and steel would become quite expensive, people would fight to access to the ruins of old cities to scavenge  any piece of metal that can be found.

Transport would be based on the Diesel engine and vegetable fuel. Coal can be turned into fuel as @ohwilleke mentioned, but it is too expensive and coal resources will already be stretched. Trouble is that vegetable fuels are limited as well. Cycling will become the main mean of personal transport.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to refine question a bit: what kind of apocalypse?

It is very important to your story. For example: random or targeted, slow or fast, global or somewhat localized? Answering that gives you your base to work with.

For example modern rural area inhabitants - at least in first- and second- world countries - are technically and technologically skilled folk. They will be able to switch to steam power and coal-powered electricity rather quick, provided some equipment and infrastructure stays intact. If you destroy medium and large population centers, you will loose a lot of higher science and technology knowledge AND resources and simultaneously reduce the needed food supply, thus food producers have some time to adapt to new reality.

If you take away infrastructure, you also are quickly killing off large population - again, as above, food is critical at first, but you also prolong the recovery, because apart from knowledge, you also need to rebuild some industrial capacity to build necessary tools.

And so on and so forth.

Having said that, there are some answers that will apply generally:

1. First of all, idea is the catalyst. If you have people who at least know some things can be done, even from totally technically(or technologically) ignorant description savvy people can work out a lot of answers on their own. So if there is some knowledge retention from pre-apocalypse, it will be very quick
2. No disaster is complete (well, see beginning of the answer), so there ALWAYS be something from old times to work with.
3. Size and composition of your population is key, as is always. I am of the opinion (based on some facts and research) that most of the world was poor for this long was because of war, famine and pestilence (latter two usually due to first), because there was no excess labor available for activities beyond food production and war-making for very, very long time...

So to bottom line: coal-powered industry is rather quick and easy to achieve, provided your starting point is good enough. Which takes me back to the beginning: what is it?

Answer (score 0):

### Plastics and chemicals in general are more expensive

Almost all plastics, as well as a myriad of crucial chemicals, are  byproducts of oil and gas.

You might be OK for energy but the petrochemical sector is going to have real trouble.

On the plus side, you still have sulfuric acid, sodium hydroxide, and chlorine. You can make ammonia easily enough using syngas.

Methanol is much more expensive, many other simple organic molecules are scarce or gone, especially aromatic hydrocarbons. Dyes and hydrocarbon solvents are out. Plastic is out. Ethanol is OK. Pharmaceuticals are rooted.

Out = Scarce and expensive to a degree we can hardly imagine, and needs to be deliberately produced in small quantities, not yielded by the tonne continuously.

It will be 'easy enough' to get back to 1850 or 1900 technology; getting to 1950 / 1990 / 2020 will be incredibly difficult.